# How do I modify the following code so that I'm actually reading in the contents of the file into an array then printing out the array?

Tags: c++, arrays, file, token

The following code reads in a text file then prints it to the screen. It works perfectly however I want to first read in the contents into an array then print out the contents and I'm not sure how to do so.

```
#include <fstream> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
string input;
```

//Open file

```
std::ifstream inFile; 
inFile.open("Input.txt");

while (true) 
{
```

//Get input

```
inFile >> input;
```

//Avoid repetition of last line:

```
if(inFile.eof() ) break;
```

//Print input on the screen

```
if (input == "a")
    std::cout << "Variable: " << input << "\n";

if (input == "=")
    std::cout << "Assignment: " << input << "\n";

if (input == "3")
    std::cout << "Integer: " << input << "\n";

if (input == ";")
    std::cout << "Semicolon: " << input << "\n";

if (input == "+")
    std::cout << "Operator: " << input << "\n";

if (input == "5")
    std::cout << "Integer: " << input << "\n";

if (input == "31")
    std::cout << "Integer: " << input << "\n";

if (input == "b")
    std::cout << "Variable: " << input << "\n";

if (input == "*")
    std::cout << "Operator: " << input << "\n";

if (input == "A")
    std::cout << "Variable: " << input << "\n";

if (input == "4")
    std::cout << "Integer: " << input << "\n";

if (input == "-")
    std::cout << "Operator: " << input << "\n";

if (input == "quit")
    std::cout << "Word: " << input << "\n";
}
```

//Close file

```
inFile.close();
return 0;
}
```

End of program

Answer (score 1):

You could store the elements in a `std::vector<int>` and `push_back` each element one by one until the end of file.Then you could loop through your vector to display all the elements.

If you prefer using simple arrays, you would have to count how many elements you have in your file, allocate that much memory to your array with `new`, and store the elements into your array. Don't forget to `delete[] your_array` in the end.